# SQL statistics on large databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is a good way to handle statistics on SQL 2008 for very large databases? Multiple tables with 100m+ rows in each.

Should auto update statistics be on? Will auto update statistics async help at all? should a job be setup to manually update statistics on some kind of schedule?

Usually data is added to the table but older data isn't changed very often.

Update: About 100k rows inserted each hour. Mostly reporting is done on the data. Updates can happen on 1-2 columns on ~500k rows per day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one I would not want update stats to run in the middle of the day on a large table, so I would say no. Also you need to hit the threshold (20% I believe) before it kicks in anyway

Now if you have a job already that rebuilds the index then stats are updated automatically (this is not true with a reorg/defrag)

Also 100 million rows doesn't mean much, how many columns if the table is 12 bytes wide (per row) compared to 4100 bytes that is a big difference (especially since with the 4100 bytes per row table you can only fir 1 row per page)

Comment: looking at 10192, 74, and 506

Answer (score 1):

> What is a good way to handle statistics on SQL 2008 for very large databases? Multiple tables with 
>   100m+ rows in each.

PLEASE dont call this very large. I give you an example of very large. We just run a sql statement on some data in our warehouse. Temp space usage tops at 180gb. For that statement. Db? two digits terabytes. 100m+ rows are not small, but not very large.

> Should auto update statistics be on? Will auto update statistics async help at all? should a job 
>   be setup to manually update statistics on some kind of schedule?

Depend. On update and usage patterns.

> Usually data is added to the table but older data isn't changed very often.

How often? How much in percentage? What data? Do the statistics get out of scope fast or slowly move? YOu ahve to provide a LOT more information to make sensible suggestions.

Comment: True, also a 1 column 100 million row table is peanuts compared to a 55 column 100 million row table

Comment: added a bit more info to my question. I say this is a very large database because it's 500GB in size, not because of the row count. Queries can take the tempdb into 250GB size

Comment: 500GB is not a VLDB these days...Petabytes size databases are common. if you have tempdb growing to 250GB then you might consider adding indexes on the columns that you are ordering by, sort operations happen in tempdb..but you need to test first

Answer (score 1):

> Should auto update statistics be on?

It Depends...

> Will auto update statistics async help
>   at all?

It will help prevent a stats update that takes a long time from killing a query. Basically this tells SQL Server that if a query comes in and it realizes stats are outdated instead of holding the query, updating the stats, then running the query. just run the query and update the stats behind the scenes. So that particular query that kicked off the need for a stats update won't get any benefits but it also won't sit around waiting for the stats to update first either.

> should a job be setup to manually
>   update statistics on some kind of
>   schedule?

Yes! Stats are only updated if 20% of a tables data has been "changed". On very big tables that can basically be the same as saying stats will never be updated. If you have any large tables where new data is being added you should always have a scheduled process to update stats on them.

Answer (score 1):

"It depends" is a good answer but in the absence of reproducable and measurable improvement I'd leave it at the default.

If you update stats manually overnight then you have less chance of an auto-update kicking in. And you can defer a stats update by setting [AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397.aspx) (See "When to Use Synchronous or Asynchronous Statistics Updates")

On balance I wouldn't disable it or change the default which is "on".